# 2 questions about formatted text fields

Tags: java

I want the JFormattedTextField to accept any decimal number greater than 0, but am unable to figure out how to do this using the DecimalFormat class?

Also, I have limited my text field to 10 columns.  When I programmatically set a number with more than 10 digits (1.333...) the text field display scrolled to the right, such that it just shows 10 3s, "3333333...".  I would like it to display to be scrolled to the left, so that it shows the first 10 digits, "1.333..."  Any suggestions how to force it to be scrolled to the left when displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Using `MaskFormatter` will help you limit the text field to allow upto 10 digits.

```
        try {           
            MaskFormatter format = new MaskFormatter("");
            // Allows you to enter any digit greater than 0.
            format.setInvalidCharacters("0");
            JFormattedTextField inputField = new JFormattedTextField( format );

            // Add FocusListener and onFocusLost set the caret position to the zeroth position.
            inputField.setCaretPosition(0);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: not really what i was asking.  i asked how to limit the field to decimals > 0, and how to display the left most digit when the field displays.  users may enter infinite digits, 10 columns works to only display 10 digits at a time.